# Swift model not get updated from table cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableviewcontoller, it retrieves the data and stores in model objects. The model object is assigned to table cells. when i make a change in table cell text box, the changes are not get updated to model. Is anything wrong in this code? if this is not right approach, please let know how to get the changes in table row.

```
 class myTable: UITableViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

 var models = [Customer]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     self.generateUpdateModels()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
} 

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return models.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rowIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TextInputLabelTableViewCell

        cell.first.text = models[indexPath.row].first //label
        cell.last.text = models[indexPath.row].last   //label 
        cell.status.text = models[indexPath.row].status //textbox

    return cell
}

func generateUpdateModels(){
  //update models[]
}

@IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {

    //look into models for changes....
    // don't see the changes
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("final", sender: self)

}
```

Comment: You need to create a delegate for the textbox and update the model when textbox changes

Comment: @Gasim, can you provide some examples/link for this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/ManageTextFieldTextViews/ManageTextFieldTextViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH10-SW1

Comment: @Gasim, Tobias, thanks. it helped to solve the issue